# How to get back filenames on notepad taskbar icons?

Tags: windows-11, notepad

There always were filenames of an opened file on a taskbar but suddenly there are only "Notepad". See

Screenshot of issue:

[image: screenshot].

Comment: That is how the new Notepad works, and I believe that is a result of the new Tabbed Interface.  Report it in Feedback as a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't happen for me with the latest
[Notepad++ v8.4.9](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/).

I suggest to uninstall Notepad++ and install the latest version.

If this still happens, open menu *Settings > Preferences* and in section
"MISC" set "Show only filename in title bar" and see if this helps.

Comment: It is Notepad and not Notepad++. I just installed Notepad++. It shows full path on taskbar.. So I do not see the filename.

Comment: Set "Show only filename in title bar" to see only the file-name part. Note : This doesn't happen to me either with notepad on Windows 10. Are you on Windows 11?

Comment: yes. windows 11. that was nice to talk with you. chat with somebody is rare for me

Comment: As I noted, newest version of Windows 11 has changed all this.

Comment: Must be a bug because of the multi-tabs. Using Notepad++ will solve it.

Comment: Does Notepad++ support multi windows by default?

Comment: Notepad++ is a very advanced text editor. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30745411/open-two-instances-of-notepad).